# Sql getting figures with 0 for latest month

Tags: sql-server

A very complicated issue I have below.

Here is a query I have

```
SELECT distinct sending_organisation AS [Supplier]
, t1.date
, COUNT(Status) AS [Transactions]
,  Month(t1.Date) SO_Month
, Year(t1.date) SO_Year
FROM TX
CROSS APPLY 
( 
    VALUES 
    (
        CONCAT
        (
            left(DATENAME(mm, Date_Reported),3)
            ,' '
            ,DATENAME(yyyy, Date_Reported)
        )
        ,DATEPART(mm, Date_Reported)
    )
) t1 (Date, Morder)
where Date >= DATEADD(MONTH, -13, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))
GROUP BY t1.date, t1.Morder, sending_organisation
ORDER BY sending_organisation, date DESC
```

The result gives me a list of all suppliers and their transactions over the last 13 months, something like this:

```
Supplier | Date | Transactions
```

What I would now like is the exact same query, **but only select the suppliers with a "0" value in transactions for the latest month**. So the tale will look the same but the rows will be less.

Any idea, the issue I have is the above query does not give me a list of suppliers with a "0" so i cannot put a restriction.

Thanks in advance

Comment: without seeing your schema and some sample data, and an expected result, this is going to be quite hard for people to figure out. We can only see part of the picture.

Comment: Wouldn't you need to use the table Suppliers for that? This table sounds to be related to Suppliers in a 1-to-Many fashion. Also, as a side note, your expression in cross apply wouldn't provide an ordering by year-month (chronological) but month-year (December all years first, Novembers next and so on).

Comment: I don't have a table suppliers, i just have one table to work from which is the TX table and the rest are columns within